# How to document the return value of a method in Objective C and Oxygen with Xcode 6?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, doxygen

I am currently trying to document some pieces of code. I am using Xcode version 6 and tried to document a method with a return value.

```
/** 
 @brief TODO
 @param url TODO
 @param interval TODO
 @return id TODO.
 */
-(id) initWithUrl: (NSString*) url andInterval: (int) interval;
```

Without the line with @return Xcode shows the documentation of the method correctly in the Quick Help, when I drag my cursor above or combine the options key with a mouse click.

Can someone tell me whats wrong with it? How does the correct documentation with oxygen have to look like?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes doing nothing helps. Additionally I read an article that says:

> If your popover didn’t contain your comment, you may not have waited long enough for the project to build. If it has finished, try restarting Xcode, just to make sure.

Source: [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/66395/documenting-in-xcode-with-headerdoc-tutorial)